# How to restrict EditText to two lines in android

Tags: android, android-edittext

Hi i need to restrict the EditText to two lines and i am using the following code

```
<EditText
android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/valettext"
android:layout_centerVertical="true"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_marginRight="70dp"
android:maxLines="2"
android:ellipsize="end"
android:id="@+id/note"/>
```

but its not working ,its going to the next line on pressing the Next button.

How to do this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Duplicated

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7092961/edittext-maxlines-not-working-user-can-still-input-more-lines-than-set

Comment: Please check my code here...

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8911638/set-maximum-number-of-text-lines-for-an-edittext/23310236#23310236

Answer (score 2):

You need to add this:

```
android:singleLine="false"
```

Also, set the number of lines prior to display:

```
android:lines="2"
```

Comment: This shows user two lines but when a third one is inputed, the EditText is expanded. See my solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7092961/edittext-maxlines-not-working-user-can-still-input-more-lines-than-set/7103931

Answer (score 2):

override your edittext's `addaddTextChangedListener()` and inside `afterTextChanged()` method try this code.

```
 @Override
 public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {
    if (null != edittext.getLayout() && edittext.getLayout().getLineCount() > 2)  {
       edittext.getText().delete(edittext.getText().length() - 1, edittext.getText().length());
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<EditText
   android:id="@+id/edit_text"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:inputType="text"
   android:maxLines="1"  />
```

You just need to make sure you have the attribute "inputType" set. It doesn't work without this line.

```
android:inputType="text"
```