# android how to make text in an edittext exactly fixed lines

Tags: android, android-edittext

I want to allow use to enter just 5 lines, I tried this

```
<EditText
    android:layout_below="@+id/tv_signup_descriptionError"
    android:id="@+id/et_signup_description"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dip"
    android:hint="@string/et_hint_enterDescription"
    android:singleLine="false"
    android:lines="5"
    android:gravity="top"
    android:scrollHorizontally="false"
    android:inputType="textMultiLine" 
    android:maxLines="5"/>
```

but still I can press `Enter` after the fifth line

Comment: Possible duplicate of [EditText maxLines not working - user can still input more lines than set](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7092961/edittext-maxlines-not-working-user-can-still-input-more-lines-than-set)

Comment: Try this code
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8911638/set-maximum-number-of-text-lines-for-an-edittext

Comment: You can limit the number of characters by adding android:maxLength.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot do that using any XML attributes.

`maxlines` represents the `maximum height` of the EditText and **not** the number of input lines.

You can however implement your own code to check for the number of lines.

The following is **not my own code**, but is taken from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7092961/edittext-maxlines-not-working-user-can-still-input-more-lines-than-set/7103931).

```
mEditText.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {

            // if enter is pressed start calculating
            if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER
                    && event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_UP) {

                // get EditText text
                String text = ((EditText) v).getText().toString();

                // find how many rows it cointains
                editTextRowCount = text.split("\\n").length;

                // user has input more than limited - lets do something
                // about that
                if (editTextRowCount >= 7) {

                    // find the last break
                    int lastBreakIndex = text.lastIndexOf("\n");

                    // compose new text
                    String newText = text.substring(0, lastBreakIndex);

                    // add new text - delete old one and append new one
                    // (append because I want the cursor to be at the end)
                    ((EditText) v).setText("");
                    ((EditText) v).append(newText);

                }
            }

            return false;
        }
```

Comment: your code make the edittext to empty when i press the first enter , why ?

Comment: `((EditText) v).setText("");` remove this part if you dont want that.

Comment: sorry , your code doesn't work :(, i still can press `enter` after the fifth line

Comment: Well, if you look closely in the code, you will see that the code was written for 7 lines and not 5 lines. Just change the `7` to `5` and I hope it will work.

Comment: yes yes i know 7:) i press `enter` 80 times and still can, please would you correct the code?

Comment: if you don't know , don't worry i can start new quesiton

Comment: @FernadoMargin : I think that will be much appreciated. Because as of now, I really dont have the time to debug the code. I didn't even try it myself. Maybe I will have a look at it sometime later. Gotta rush now. Sorry.

Answer (score 6):

@Swayam you are right, But this solution has improved :

1- better performance

2- in your solution if you entered 7 lines (your max input lines) then pressed enter in Top lines the last line will be delete, But **in this solution "enter" key has ignored.**

```
 mEditText.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {

                if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER  && event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {

                    if ( ((EditText)v).getLineCount() >= 7 )
                        return true;
                    }

                return false;
            }
     });
```

Comment: This solution misses the case of calling setText via code.

Comment: as doc, this works only with hardware keyboard
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnKeyListener.html

Comment: Works for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The maxLines attribute is to limit height of the EditText. To limit maximum number of lines you have to do it yourself in code.

Answer (score 0):

/** MAX_LINES You want to set */

```
  public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {
        int lines = mEditText.getLineCount();
        if (lines > MAX_LINES) {
            String s = editable.toString();
            int start = mEditText.getSelectionStart();
            int end = mEditText.getSelectionEnd();

            if (start == end && start < s.length() && start > 1) {
                s = s.substring(0, start - 1) + s.substring(start);
            } else {
                s = s.substring(0, s.length() - 1);
            }

            mEditText.setText(s);
            mEditText.setSelection(mEditText.getText().length());
            // Toast.makeText(RatingActivity.this, "max line set to MAX_LINES", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
  }
```

This piece of code works for me to set the EditText max lines limit to MAX_LINES.