# How to restrict the user to enter more than 5 lines in edit text?

Tags: android, android-edittext

I am developing an android application with some forms. Here in my input fields description section should not allow the user to enter more than 5 lines.I am not getting how to prevent the user to enter more than 5 lines in edit text field. I already tried `android:maxLines=5` and `android:lines=5`. But those are not giving my functionality. could any one please suggest a way to stop entering more than 5 lines in edit text.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Check this question here: [EditText maxLines not working - user can still input more lines than set](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7092961/edittext-maxlines-not-working-user-can-still-input-more-lines-than-set). See the answer by _Indrek Kõue_.

Answer (score 0):

Validate the field when the user tries to submit it. Use a prompt to notify the user of the required length.

Answer (score 0):

`android:maxLines` and `android:lines` limits the number of visible lines, `android:maxLines=5` expands the edittext up to 5 lines, and `android:lines=5` creates a span of 5 lines.

if you want to limit the length of the input you need to use the `android:maxLength=5` as shown in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3285421/1056359

Answer (score 0):

mmm, i think this need more calculations depending on font size and the line width, so in this case i prefer just to set the `maxLength` attribute to like 100 character, otherwise you need to calculate the current text size while user typing into it.