# Android: How do I get an EditText I made in Java to stop expanding vertically

Tags: android, android-edittext, tablelayout, android-tablelayout

I have an editText I made in a TableLayout, I want it to have 5 lines but if I press enter a bunch of times it'll expand the editText box on the screen. I can't figure out how to get this to stop.

```
LayoutParams bigedit = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT); //width height
bigedit.weight=1;
bigedit.setMargins(10, 0, 0, 10);//Left Top Right Bottom

EditText testEdit1= new EditText(this);
testEdit1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.black_rect_border);
testEdit1.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_MULTI_LINE);
testEdit1.setLines(5);
testEdit1.setMaxLines(5);
testEdit1.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(true);
testEdit1.setId(unusedid);
testEdit1.setSingleLine(false);
testEdit1.setGravity(Gravity.TOP|Gravity.LEFT);
unusedid++;
testEdit1.setTextSize(16);
testEdit1.setLayoutParams(bigedit);

row1.addView(testEdit1);
tl.addView(row1);
```

Where tl is the TableLayout in the activity.

Answer (score 0):

See the code provided in one of the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7092961/edittext-maxlines-not-working-user-can-still-input-more-lines-than-set/7103931), which might help you out.

Comment: I even put in MaxLines and it still expands the boundaries rather than keeping it set and having a scroll wheel (which is acceptable in my case)

Comment: It's not the *accepted* answer to the linked question but the one underneath with the longer code sample that I figured may help you out.

Answer (score 0):

Just guessing, but according to `setSingleLine` docs.-

> setSingleLine(boolean singleLine) If true, sets the properties of this
>   field (lines, horizontally scrolling, transformation method) to be for
>   a single-line input; if false, restores these to the default
>   conditions.

This line.-

```
testEdit1.setSingleLine(false);
```

could be overriding your `maxLines` setting. Just try and remove that line, there's no need for it, anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Well I got it to work (except the vertical scroll bar), oddly by changing the order of those statements.

```
EditText testEdit1= new EditText(this);
testEdit1.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(true);
testEdit1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.black_rect_border);
testEdit1.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_MULTI_LINE);    
testEdit1.setLines(5);
testEdit1.setSingleLine(false);
testEdit1.setMaxLines(5);
testEdit1.setGravity(Gravity.TOP|Gravity.LEFT);
testEdit1.setId(unusedid);
unusedid++;
testEdit1.setTextSize(16);
testEdit1.setLayoutParams(bigedit);
```

Apparently the setinput line only works if you set the class to type text using

```
testEdit1.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT | InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_MULTI_LINE);
```