# Maxlines not working when inputType is textMultiLine

Tags: android, xml, android-edittext

This is my Edittext's xml code

```
        <EditText
        android:id="@+id/meeting_who_was_txt"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingLeft="15dp"
        android:gravity="top"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:paddingRight="15dp"
        android:inputType="textMultiLine"
        android:maxLines="2"/>
```

This is java code

```
  meetingWhoWas=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.meeting_who_was_txt);
  meetingWhoWas.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());
```

when i run my app,multiLine working perfect in Edittext,but maxlines not working.
What is a wrong in my code and how i can solve my problem?

Comment: See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7092961/edittext-maxlines-not-working-user-can-still-input-more-lines-than-set

Answer (score 1):

You just need to make sure you have the attribute "inputType" set. It doesn't work without this line.

`android:inputType="text"`

Answer (score -1):

See the [Documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html)

1. Attribute `android:inputType="textMultiLine"` allows `multiple lines` of text in the `EditText` field. If this flag is not set, the `EditText` field will be constrained to a `single line`.
2. Attribute `android:maxLines="2"` represensts the height of `EditText`. It makes `EditText` be at most two lines tall.

**For single line `EditText` use:**

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/meeting_who_was_txt"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="text"
    android:maxLines="1"/>
```

**For multiple line `EditText` use:**

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/meeting_who_was_txt"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="textMultiLine"
    android:maxLines="2"/>
```

Hope this will help~

Comment: what is a different between mine and your code ? @Ferdous Ahamed

Comment: Please read my point 1 and 2. I have add XML codes just for understanding about SingleLine and MultipleLine EditText. Thank you~