# Difficulty with maxlines in edittext

Tags: android

For Android EditText maxlines=true does not work if digits are applied and single line true is deprecated so anyone has any suggestions?

Comment: you have to give the numbers to set the max lines for your editext. Like set maxLines = "2" . It will work then

Comment: maxLines take integer not a boolean varibale so you should use maxLines = "1"

Comment: So... you are telling it `Set the maximum number of lines to... YES`. Does it make sense to you?

Comment: Ok so set inputType = "text" and then it should work.

Comment: watch this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7092961/edittext-maxlines-not-working-user-can-still-input-more-lines-than-set

Answer (score 2):

see this example

```
<EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="4dp"
        android:digits="1234567890ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
        android:maxLength="15"//used to set max character
        android:maxLines="1"/>//used to set max number of lines
```

[image]

Comment: It does'nt work if u put android:digits="abcd". Check yourself.

Comment: @Rudee why would you put `android:digits="abcd"`? I mean, what for?

Comment: @Rudee I have checked and its working for me, so before commenting please do some research and try something, check my revised abswer

Answer (score 0):

Put this code in your activity

```
editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
editText.setSingleLine(true);
```

This is how your xml will look

```
<EditText
android:id="@+id/editText"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:digits="abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
android:maxLines="1"
android:textColor="@android:color/black"/>
```

Comment: put android:digits="abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz" and then check maxlines will not work.

Answer (score 0):

I think you didnt specify this parameter:

```
android:inputType="text"
```

Without it you can even put new line in edit text.
You could add also these attributes:

```
 android:maxLines="1"
 android:lines="1"
```

Though when I checked it without inputType attribute, it still didn't work.
Hope I helped